# Vim macro with backspace

Tags: javascript, vim, macros

I'm trying to save a vim macro that includes the backspace character to my vimrc file. The idea of this macro is to add a documentation segment in a js file. So if I have the following function:

```
function foo() {
}
```

I'll put the cursor on the function line, run the macro and it will create:

```
function foo() {
    /*
    | <- Cursor ends up here in insert mode.
    */
}
```

When I created the macro I got the following register:

```
o/*^M<80>kb<80>kb<80>kb*/<80>ku^M<80>kb<80>kb<80>kb
```

(<80> is a single character)

I tried adding this as a let command:

```
let a='o/*^M<80>kb<80>kb<80>kb*/<80>ku^M<80>kb<80>kb<80>kb'
```

but when I run it it just prints out:

```
function foo() {
    /*^M<80>kb<80>kb<80>kb*/<ESC>O<80>kb<80>kb<80>kb 
}
```

Is there some escaping that I'm missing? Maybe there's a different and better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those `<80>kb` are the internal key code for backspace. Replace each with `\<BS>` (and write `^M` as `\<CR>`), and put the entire macro string in *double quotes*, and you should be good to go.

Also, to assign to register a, you need to use `@a`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I couldn't find the code for backspace

Comment: See `:h key-notation`.

Answer (score 3):

All those `<80>kb` don't matter: they are used internally by Vim but you don't need them at all.

Keep in mind that a macro is nothing more than a series of keystrokes. If you know what you do it's really not hard to "conceptualize" your actions/keystrokes and write them down directly *without* the recording step or even without Vim itself. That's what all the regulars here or on #vim do: Vim being a language, you only have to think about the steps needed to achieve your goal and you have your macro:

```
o/*^M*/^[O

o    open a new line below the current line
/*   insert /*
^M   insert a line break
*/   insert */
^[   go back to normal mode
O    open a new line above the current line
```

To use that macro in a function, use the `:normal` command that allows you to execute normal mode commands from the command-line or from a vimscript context:

```
:norm! o/*^M*/^[O
```

Use that macro directly in a mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> o/*^M*/^[O
```

To save that macro in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let @a = "o/*^M*/^[O"
```

and press `@a`.

**Important reminder:**

```
^M is obtained with <C-v><CR>
^[ is obtained with <C-v><Esc>
```

Reference:

```
:help recording
:help registers
:help :normal
:help i_ctrl-v
```

Comment: Thanks, you made my day with the <C-v> tip. It allows to easily insert CR, Esc, BS and others while editing a macro in a buffer...